# The file "Resource id #11" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a class that converts an array into plaintext and file. Plaintext works fine however when I try to save it as a tmpfile and share it I'm getting errors.

My **controller** looks like:

```php
public method index() {
    $props = ['foo'=>'bar']; //array of props;
    return response()->download(MyClass::create($props);
    // I've also tried using return response()->file(MyClass::create($props);
}
```

And my **class** looks like:

```php
class MyClass
{
    // transform array to plain text and save
    public static function create($props)
    {

        // I've tried various read/write permissions here with no change.
        $file = fopen(tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix'), 'w');
        fwrite($file,  implode(PHP_EOL, $props));

            return $file;
    }

    // I've also tried File::put('filename', implode(PHP_EOL, $props)) with the same results.
}
```

And I'm getting a file not found exception:

> `The file "Resource id #11" does not exist.`

I've tried tmpfile, tempname and others and get the same exception. I've tried passing MyClass::create($props)['uri'] and I got

> `The file "" does not exist`

Is this an error due to my env (valet) or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: It should work fine. Have you tried file_put_contents()? What did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is mixing up usage of *filenames* and *file handles*:

- [tempnam()](http://php.net/tempnam) returns a string: the path to a newly created temporary file
- [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen) accesses a file at a given path, and returns a "resource" - a special type in PHP used to refer to system resources; in this case, the resource is more specifically a "file handle"
- if you use a resource where a string was expected, PHP will just give you a label describing the resource, such as "Resource id #11"; as far as I know, there is no way to get back the filename of an open file handle

In your `create` definition, `$file` is the result of `fopen()`, so is a "resource" value, the open file handle. Since you `return $file`, the result of `MyClass::create($props)` is also the file handle.

The Laravel [`response()->download(...)` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads) is expecting a string, the filename to access; when given a resource, it silently converts it to string, resulting in the error seen.

To get the filename, you need to make two changes to your `create` function:

- Put the result of `tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix')` in a variable, e.g. `$filename`, before calling `$file = fopen($filename, 'w');`
- Return `$filename` instead of `$file`

You should also add a call to `fclose($file)` before returning, to cleanly close the file after writing your data to it.

As an alternative to the `fopen`/`fwrite`/`fclose` sequence, you can use [file_get_contents()](https://php.net/file_get_contents), which takes a filename (as a string) and some data (as a string), and creates or overwrites the whole file in one call.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help. I'd add to this that file_put_contents is the nicer way to handle this as it truncates the process combining fopen, fwrite and fclose. 

I did the following:

```php

public function create(array $props): string
{
    $filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix') . '.txt';
    file_put_contents($filename, $this->implode("\r\n", $props) . self::$

    return $filename;
}

```

I also changed PHP_EOL with "\r\n" as PHP_EOL changes based on the system your PHP is running and for my file I specifically needed a CRLF linebreak.